# Swapping the OneOnOne related instances between two model instances without running into an IntegrityError

Tags: django, django-orm

I have these two models:

```
class Item(models.model):
    space = models.OneToOneField(Space, null=False, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Space(models.Model):
    ...
```

An Item is linked to a single Space. A Space can only contain one Item.

I want to swap the Items:

```
item_1 = Item.objects.get(id=1)
item_2 = Item.objects.get(id=2)

space_1 = Item.objects.get(id=1)
space_2 = Item.objects.get(id=2)

assert(item_1.space == space_1) # True
assert(item_2.space == space_2) # True

# Switching spaces results in an IntegrityError (of course)

item_1.space = item_2.space
item_2.space = item_1.space

item_1.save() # IntegrityError

Item.objects.bulk_update([item_1, item_2], ['space']) # IntegrityError
```

I am now using a temporary Space that I create to swap the Items and that I delete afterwards. I was wondering if there's a more efficient way of swapping these Items' Spaces without running into an IntegrityError.

Comment: Do you use MySQL, since MySQL is notorious in how it checks constraints.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11207946/67579

Comment: I'm currently just testing it locally on sqlite, but production is on Postgresql.